# Failed to run django app using docker containers

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm trying to run a Django app on `localhost:8000`.

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that creates 3 containers:

- badgr-server_api
- badgr-server_memcached
- badgr-server_db_

When I run docker-compose up it says starting 2 of the containers and creating the 3rd (`badgr-server_api`) and I only see memchaced and db running, see screenshot. I have tried deleting the `badgr-server_api` and running it again, I tried removing the image.

I also ran `docker-compose build` again but I just can't get it to run. I hope someone can help please.

[docker-compose up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHNtN.png)

After running docker, I also ran this command:

```
docker-compose exec api python /badgr_server/manage.py migrate
```

and get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/badgr_server/manage.py", line 13, in <module>
   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 212, in get_connection_params
    isolation_level = options.pop('isolation_level', 'read committed')
TypeError: pop() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
# A dockerized badgr-server stack for development
version: '3.3'
services:

  # this container mirrors in the app code and runs the django dev server
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile.dev.api
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "memcached"
    command: /badgr_server/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/badgr_server/apps
      - ./manage.py:/badgr_server/manage.py
      - ./.docker/etc/settings_local.dev.py:/badgr_server/apps/mainsite/settings_local.py
    networks:
      - badgr
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  # this container runs memcached
  memcached:
    image: 'bitnami/memcached:latest'
    expose:
      - "11211"
    networks:
      - badgr

  # this container runs mysql (database)
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.39
    volumes:
      - badgr_server_dev_db:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./.docker/etc/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=password"
      - "MYSQL_HOST=db"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    networks:
      - badgr

networks:
  badgr:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  badgr_server_dev_db:
```

```
> import random import string from .settings import * from mainsite
> import TOP_DIR
> 
> DEBUG = False DEBUG_ERRORS = DEBUG DEBUG_STATIC = DEBUG DEBUG_MEDIA =
> DEBUG
> 
> TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles' LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
> 
> 
> ##
> #
> # Database Configuration
> #
> ## DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
>         'NAME': 'badgr',
>         'USER': 'root',
>         'PASSWORD': 'password',
>         'HOST': 'db',
>         'PORT': '',
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             "SET character_set_connection=utf8mb3, collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci"
>             #            ,  # Uncomment when using MySQL to ensure consistency across servers
>         },
>     } }
> 
> 
> ###
> #
> # CACHE
> #
> ### CACHES = {
>      'default': {
>          'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
>          'LOCATION': 'memcached:11211',
>          'KEY_FUNCTION': 'mainsite.utils.filter_cache_key'
>      }  }
> 
> 
> 
> ###
> #
> # Email Configuration
> #
> ### DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@example.com'  # e.g. "noreply@example.com" EMAIL_BACKEND =
> 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
> 
> 
> ###
> #
> # Celery Asynchronous Task Processing (Optional)
> #
> ### CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
> # Run celery tasks in same thread as webserver (True means that asynchronous processing is OFF) CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
> 
> 
> ###
> #
> # Application Options Configuration
> #
> ### HTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://localhost:8000' ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] STATIC_URL = HTTP_ORIGIN + '/static/'
> 
> CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
>     'http://localhost:4200', )
> 
> # Optionally restrict issuer creation to accounts that have the 'issuer.add_issuer' permission BADGR_APPROVED_ISSUERS_ONLY = False
> 
> # Automatically send an email the first time that recipient identifier (email type) has been used on the system.
> GDPR_COMPLIANCE_NOTIFY_ON_FIRST_AWARD = True
> 
> SECRET_KEY = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase +
> string.digits) for _ in range(40)) UNSUBSCRIBE_KEY =
> ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in
> range(40)) UNSUBSCRIBE_SECRET_KEY = str(SECRET_KEY)
> 
> 
> ###
> #
> # Logging
> #
> ### LOGS_DIR = os.path.join(TOP_DIR, 'logs') if not os.path.exists(LOGS_DIR):
>     os.makedirs(LOGS_DIR) LOGGING = {
>     'version': 1,
>     'disable_existing_loggers': False,
>     'handlers': {
>         'mail_admins': {
>             'level': 'ERROR',
>             'filters': [],
>             'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
>         },
> 
>         # badgr events log to disk by default
>         'badgr_events': {
>             'level': 'INFO',
>             'formatter': 'json',
>             'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
>             'filename': os.path.join(LOGS_DIR, 'badgr_events.log')
>         }
>     },
>     'loggers': {
>         'django.request': {
>             'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
>             'level': 'ERROR',
>             'propagate': True,
>         },
> 
>         # Badgr.Events emits all badge related activity
>         'Badgr.Events': {
>             'handlers': ['badgr_events'],
>             'level': 'INFO',
>             'propagate': False,
> 
>         }
> 
>     },
>     'formatters': {
>         'default': {
>             'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s'
>         },
>         'json': {
>             '()': 'mainsite.formatters.JsonFormatter',
>             'format': '%(asctime)s',
>             'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z',
>         }
>     }, }
```

Comment: Can you should us your settings file, especially the database part ?

Comment: This might happend because your DATABASE settings is a list when it should be a dict.

Comment: The only thing the screenshot shows is that the api server is not producing output. It may be running.

Comment: Thanks @Taek I have added the settings file and I will look into the Database settings, I thought it was a dict. As you can tell I am new to this but thanks for your help and if you see anything in the settings file please let me know.

Comment: @NickODell on the 4th line it shows 'done' which I presume means the container is running without any problems yet it does not show any further info like it does with the other 2 containers. Thanks for taking the time to leave your feedback.

Comment: ok so I found the solution. I commented out:

"SET character_set_connection=utf8mb3, collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci"

in the settings file in the database config under options. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @Elena You might be able to make it work while keeping the options you had in the first place, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DATABASES.default.OPTIONS` should be a dictionary and not a set, it's a bit tricky to see the difference between the two if you're not used to it:

```
In [5]: type({'key': 'value'})
Out[5]: dict

In [6]: type({'key and no value'})
Out[6]: set
```

That's why you got the `pop() takes no arguments (2 given)` error message, since that's how `set.pop` works: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.pop

You should be able to make it work without commenting the options by using a properly formated dict such as :

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        ...
        "OPTIONS": {
            "character_set_connection": "utf8mb3",
            "collation_connection": "utf8_unicode_ci",
        },
    }
}
```

I'm no sure of the exact syntax espacialy the values `"utf8mb3"` and `"utf8_unicode_ci"` should be enums i think. I don't have a mysql db to try it on so you'll have to find that yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right, it should be a dict :)